# I'm trying to put a direct <a> to a link inside a <td> but I don't know what's wrong

Tags: php, html-table

I'm trying to put `<a>` which it directs into a link when we click inside a `<td>` but I don't know what's wrong with it .

```
echo "<td>"<a href="http://www.link.com"> "</td>";
```

Is what I did correct? If nope how and why?

Comment: Get an IDE, like PHPstorm or whatever free one - it tells you errors while you type. And/or check your error logs as they tell you errors in your code. Cannot develop code without reading the error logs, you'll save yourself hours a week if you make the effort to use them :)

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a whole lot of syntax errors.  (And you should take a look at your PHP logs, as well as enable error reporting for your debugging, so you can learn about those syntax errors.)  If you want to echo a string, just echo the string:

```
echo '<td><a href="http://www.link.com"></td>';
```

There's no need to overcomplicate it with attempts at concatenation, quoting and un-quoting things, etc.

**Additionally**, you need to finish the HTML:

```
echo '<td><a href="http://www.link.com">some text</a></td>';
```

You were missing the text to be clicked on, and the closing `</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead :
`echo "<td><a href=\"http://www.link.com\"></td>";`
double quotation (`"`) make the middle strings into a function or command .

**EDIT 2**
Way 1 (*recommend*) :

> If using single or double is not important for you , always use single
>   quotation like this :

`echo '<td><a href="http://www.link.com"></td>';`

Way 2 :

> If you must use double quotation for string define, then change double
>   quotation in your html to single , use like this :

`echo "<td><a href='http://www.link.com'></td>";`

Way 3 :

> If you must use double quotation for string define and double
>   quotation in your HTML/String , then strip it with a `\` backslash
>   before the double quotation , like this :

`echo "<td><a href=\"http://www.link.com\"></td>";`

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'www' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: this is what i get in errors logs when i try to run what you wrote in my table

Comment: This code will produce the same syntax errors, and for the same reason.

Comment: I got a mistake on answer :) , sorry , I've edited it

Comment: @ScriptingTrier , check the new , correct and full answer :)

Comment: @David , check the new , correct and full answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Close the link:

```
echo '<td><a href="http://www.link.com"></a></td>';
```

Comment: Thanks for helping